# Output to $stdout as TTY and capture output at the same time

Tags: ruby, stdout, child-process, tty

I'm trying to redirect the output of a child process to `$stdout` and capture it at the same time.

If I first capture the output and then redirect it to `$stdout` all ANSI color codes are lost because the pipe used for capturing is not a TTY.

Is there a way to make the child process think it is outputting to a TTY? I tried using `Open3.popen3` and a `StringIO` sub-class which returns `true` for `#tty?`, but I am getting this error because the redirection target has to be a file, not an object:

```
spawn': wrong exec redirect action (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: What program is (or should be) outputting ANSI color codes? I ask because many utilities with colored output have an e.g. `--color=yes` or `--color=always` option that forces them to write colored output regardless of environment.

Comment: In my case I am writing a wrapper which should work with any command. Anyways, I have found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `PTY` module can be used for this purpose.

Instead of creating a pipe with `IO.pipe`, simply use `PTY.open`, which creates a pseudo terminal which can be used like a pipe.

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.7/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html